# Python to SQL Connection. Trying to push pandas dataframe to SQL Server

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

Anyone know how to solve this error? Trying to connect to Azure SQL Server.

Thanks a ton!

> InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', u'[IM002]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this
>   error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

Comment: Can you show some demo code? I can use sqlalche to connect my azure mssql.

Comment: If the answer below works for you, could you help mark it? thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code, but just from the error message, it seams that there is some issue with your connection string.

You can use the code below for test:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

params = urllib.quote_plus \
(r'Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:yourDBServerName.database.windows.net,1433;Database=dbname;Uid=username@dbserverName;Pwd=xxx;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine_azure = create_engine(conn_str,echo=True)

print('connection is ok')
```

Hope it helps. And please let me know if any further issue.